# Using redirection in a linux shell script which run as sudo

Tags: linux, shell

I have a unix shell script which uses redirection of stdout and stderr to a log file. For example `test.sh`:

```
ls -l &>> test.log
```

My problem is that when I run the script with `sudo`:

```
sudo ./test.sh
```

The `&` is interpreted as "run in background".

Any suggestions?

Comment: to redirect both stdout and stderr

Comment: The problem is not that the `&` is running the command asynchronously, but that anyone would expect anything else!  `bash` borrowed the syntax for `&>` from `csh`, but bourne shell syntax clearly treats `&>` as a `&` command terminator followed by a zero command redirect.  A shell which does not run the command in the background is not standard compliant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess, that your script `test.sh` does not have a shebang in the first line like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Without this line several environment settings affect the way your script is executed. In your case this means that another shell like `ash`, `ksh`, `dash` or whatever will be used to execute the script due to the setting of the root user.

Answer (score 3):

What is your hash-bang line in test.sh? Make sure you specify a shell which supports that syntax. Actually I'm not sure what shell that is--neither sh, bash, ksh, nor csh have a `&>>` redirection operator--but whatever it is you'll need to explicitly specify it:

```
#!/bin/fancysh
```

Alternatively, use a more portable syntax.

```
#!/bin/sh
ls -l >> test.log 2>&1
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try running like this:

```
ls -l >> test.log 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the script didn't have the shebang line

```
#!/bin/bash
```

I should have spotted it...

Answer (score -1):

Please change the order of your redirection to

```
    ls -l >>& test.log
```